# How to perfom a mathematical operation in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I need to form a `Select` query in LINQ for a table with fields A, B, C. I need to get the values `A` and `A - B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Select(r = new { r.A, Difference = r.A - r.B })`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 from t in yourTable
 select t.A, t.A - t.B
```